# How to close an alert box when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, jquery-events

Made this custom alert box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var $alert = $('#alert');
        if ($alert.length) {
            var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                $alert.trigger('click');
            });
            $alert.animate({ height: $alert.css('line-height') || '80px' }, 200).click(function () {
                window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
                $alert.animate({ height: '0' }, 200);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I want it to be open until the user chooses to click on it or anywhere else on the screen. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that clicking anywhere (in, or out, of the `alert` box itself) is supposed to hide/remove the alert:

```
$('body').click(
    function(){
        if ($alert.is(':visible')){
            $alert.hide();
        }
    });
```

should work, I think.

Comment: going to check this out when I get home! Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to justs get rid of it, try calling the hide() function when an onclick event is triggered.

```
$.click(function() {
  $alert.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[The top answer here is excellent IMO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) It covers the part about *anywhere else on the screen*.

The way to do it is to bind a `click` event to the body and stop propagation on any event that happens inside the area that isn't supposed to trigger closing the alert.